# Setting User's Groups - Integrity Constraint Error

Tags: plugin-development, user-groups

```
$groupIds = [1, 2];
craft()->userGroups->assignUserToGroups($user, $groupIds);
```

When executed I get the following error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity     constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`letshacklondon2016`.`craft_usergroups_users`, CONSTRAINT `craft_usergroups_users_userId_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `craft_users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE). The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `craft_usergroups_users` (`groupId`, `userId`, `dateCreated`, `dateUpdated`, `uid`) VALUES (:row0_col0, :row0_col1, :row0_col2, :row0_col3, :row0_col4), (:row1_col0, :row1_col1, :row1_col2, :row1_col3, :row1_col4). Bound with :row0_col0=1, :row0_col1=Craft\UserModel::__set_state(array('elementType' => 'User', ... (etc.)
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UserGroupsService->assignUserToGroups](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/UserGroupsService#assignUserToGroups-detail) takes a user's ID as the first parameter and you're passing in the entire [UserModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/usermodel).

Change it to this and it should work:

```
craft()->userGroups->assignUserToGroups($user->id, $groupIds);
```